# Is there a way to use regex in python data.table (apart from re.match)?

Tags: python, regex, py-datatable

I am trying to convert a column in py data.table to integer. The column contains whitespace and other unwanted characters, with those removed it could be cast to integer. I am failing to do this task in py data.table (whereas I can do it in polars, python, R data.table):

```
# remove .00 if exists, minus after number etc.
df[:, update(weird_col = re.sub(r"\.[0-9]{0,2}|-", "", df[:, 'weird_col']))] 

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

or

```
df[:, update(weird_col = re.sub(r"\.[0-9]{0,2}|-", "", df['weird_col']))]
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. However, dt data.frames do not have a .str attribute, i.e.:
"AttributeError: 'datatable.Frame' object has no attribute 'str'" error is given for such endeavors.

Comment: @Nick suggestion is for pandas, not datatable

Comment: @langtang yes, my bad, I didn't read the question carefully enough. I've deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer is no (`re.match()` is the only function in the `dt.re` module).

However, you can do something like this:

```
from datatable import Frame, update, as_type
import re

wc = df["weird_col"].to_list()[0]
regex = r"\.[0-9]{0,2}|-"
df[:, update(weird_col = as_type(Frame([re.sub(regex, "", i) for i in wc ]), int))]
```

If you want to use `str.replace()` on a pandas series, **within a datatable call**, as suggested by @Nick, you can do this:

```
df[:, update(
    weird_col = (
        df["weird_col"]
        .to_pandas()["weird_col"]
        .str
        .replace(r"\.[0-9]{0,2}|-","", regex=True)
        .astype(int)
    )
)]
```

Comment: looking to revive the project. at least we can give it a go and build back interest. what do you think @langtang?

Comment: @sammywemmy I think python datatable is fantastic, and would be great if the project could be revived!